# Need an "IF" function that shows whether the difference of a simple subtraction is greater than a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have values in cells A3 and A2. I will be subtracting the value of A2 from A3. What I need is to be able to highlight or flag the result if the difference is greater than an absolute value of .01 from A3.

For example:
29.92-29.90= .02 (Flag)
29.92-29.95= -.03 (Flag)

Comment: You might want to search next time. Found this as first result in google: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/24/between-formula-excel/

Comment: @Jill You're trying to determine whether the result of A3 minus A2 is greater than .01 difference in absolute value? Example: 1.02 minus 1.01 = .01, which is not flagged, but 1.05 minus 1.01 = .04, which is flagged?

Comment: Are you dealing with altimeter settings with these numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question as interpreted is as follows:

`=IF(ABS(A3-A2)>0.01,"Flag","No Flag")`

This statement declares that if the absolute value of the result of A3 minus A2 is greater than .01 (negative or positive), then flag it. If the absolute value of the result is 0 or .01, then don't flag it.